# How to make view from this query or CTE?

Tags: t-sql

Here is the code I'm trying to make a view with:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct
',' +
QUOTENAME( stsd.TRM_CDE + stsd.YR_CDE) as termyear
FROM STUD_TERM_SUM_DIV stsd
WHERE stsd.TRANSACTION_STS IN ('C','H','R','P') AND stsd.YR_CDE IN ('1415','1516','1617','1718') AND stsd.TRM_CDE IN ('FA','LF','SP','LS','SU','LU') and stsd.DIV_CDE = 'GR'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'');`
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please follow [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking questions... so people can give you an adapted answers

Answer (score 2):

Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) does not allow variable declarations inside a view definition.

Ditch the variable declarations and the `@cols =`.

Add `CREATE VIEW myviewname (mycolname) AS` before the `SELECT`

We could assign an alias (column name) to teh expression returned by the outer query. That would allow us to omit the column name list in the CREATE VIEW.

```
CREATE VIEW myviewname (foo)
AS
SELECT STUFF(
          ...
       ) AS foo
```